# Why do we need to initialize a Port Clock when we use that as a peripheral I/O in STM32?

Tags: stm32

Why do we need to ENABLE a GPIO clock by RCC_AHB register when we are using of that GPIO as a Peripheral Input/Output pin?

For instance for STM32F407 **ADC1**, it has its own clock and samples the data presents on the pin by its inside defined clock through the RCC_APB register and prescaler. So i think there is no need to enable GPIO Clock, but it doesn't work in this way.

So the question is what is the job of GPIO clock generally?

Comment: The same question as [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/416899](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/416899)

Answer (score 2):

Because it was designed this way. Why? To save the power if the peripheral is not used.

GPIO clock enables the control part of the GPIO, allowing you for example to enter the analog mode, and power the input transistors.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21931938)

Comment: @Bhuwan it is the correct answer. Separate peripheral clock domains are for the power saving reasons. And it is in my answer. There is no other explanation. That is the way the STM has designed the chip. I do not see anything wrong in my answer and I do not see any reason to delete my answer

Answer (score 1):

https://fastbitlab.com/input-configuration-microcontrollers/

The gpio is connect to input data register and output data register,etc. The register need the clock to read and write, not the gpio itself.

I hope I've interpreted it correctly.